# Using azure data factory to get data from delta tables to blob

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I'm trying to get data from a delta table in Azure Databricks using Data Factory. I followed this doc [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/adls-gen2/azure-datalake-gen2-sp-access#access-adls-gen2-directly) to mount the storage and I'm using a service principal to access to the storage.

I can "preview" the data in the copy activity but when I try to transfer I get this error:

Failure to initialize configurationInvalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key
Caused by: Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key.

[image]

I even give **contributor** role to the APP and the ADF in the Databricks resource

[image]

I'm running without more ideas, so any one has tried to do this ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have configured all your prerequisites as per mentioned in the this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-databricks-delta-lake?tabs=data-factory#prerequisites).

[image]

Also, instead of this:

`"fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret" -> dbutils.secrets.get(scope="<scope-name>",key="<service-credential-key-name>")`,

Try this:

`"fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": "<key-name>"`

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you followed all steps in this manual [Access Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 using OAuth 2.0 with an Azure service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/adls-gen2/azure-datalake-gen2-sp-access):

1. Register an Azure Active Directory application
2. Create an Azure key vault and secret scope
3. Save the client secret in the Azure key vault
4. Assign roles

Then you need [to configure your Databricks cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/configure#--spark-configuration) using [this template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/adls-gen2/azure-datalake-gen2-sp-access#access-adls-gen2-directly):

insert into Spart config tab (replace with your creds)

> spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.auth.type.<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net OAuth
> spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider
> spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net <application-id>
> spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net <service-credential>
> spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/token

Please note this format for accessing secrets: [Read a secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secrets#read-a-secret)

> The syntax of the Spark configuration property or environment variable path value must be {{secrets/<scope-name>/<secret-name>}}. The value must start with {{secrets/ and end with }}.

So this line:

> spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net <service-credential>

should look like this:

> spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.yourstorageaccountname.dfs.core.windows.net **{{secrets/yoursecretscope/yoursecretname}}**